# encode data in a multi-byte noop?

Tags: assembly

I'm generating AT&T-syntax assembly files. I want to encode some data in the generated instruction stream. (I want to embed a register pointer mask that I can lookup using a fixed offset to the PC.)

I can simply use the .byte or .ascii directive and jmp over embedded data:

```
movq _label6@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
jmp _skip0
.ascii "garbage instructions; scares GDB\0"
_skip0:
movq %rax, -8(%r15)
```

However, this seems a little absurd. Is there a cleaner way to do this? The Intel manuals say  there are multi-byte NOP instructions. Is there any way to encode data in a NOP? If so, can I do it using assembly? (I don't want to generate binaries myself.)

Thanks.

Comment: No harm in generating data and jumping past it. AFAIK, several compilers generate jump-tables for switch statements directly in the code.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's plausible - http://www.asmpedia.org/index.php?title=NOP

You might be able to use different register values to encode different stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Eg to encode 'abcdef12' in NOP

```
$echo 'asm("nopq 0x12abcdef(%rax,%rax,1)");' > t.c; gcc -c t.c;objdump -d t.o
t.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   48 0f 1f 84 00 ef cd    nopq   0x12abcdef(%rax,%rax,1)
   7:   ab 12
```